# Raspberry Pi Zero W -- should I avoid female gpio headers?

Tags: gpio

I don't solder.  I've had luck with the Pimoroni Hammer Headers / Jig and the Pi Zero.  I have new project, but I don't want to buy another Jig just to get a new male header array.  The jig also came with a female header.

If I'm not using a HAT (or similar) and am only wiring components with leads and a breadboard, can I use a female header without adverse consequences?

Comment: I don't see why not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one posted anything negative about doing that, so I'm going to try it on my next build.